# C# Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Me sale el error

> 'sp_InsertaLandingPagePrueba' expects parameter '@IDUSUARIO', which
>   was not supplied, l id

se supone que se debe generar a partir del máximo pero la verdad no tengo idea de como hacerle si al insertar datos en el procedimiento almacenado si se puede.

Este es mi procedimiento almacenado

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [sp_InsertaLandingPagePrueba]                                   
(
 @USUARIOCREACION   NVARCHAR(250),                          
 @USUARIOMODIFICACION   NVARCHAR(250),                          
 @IDUSUARIO INTEGER,                            
 @NOMBRE_IMG NVARCHAR(250),                         
 @URL_IMGN VARCHAR(200),
 @URL_HREF VARCHAR(200)
)                   
AS                                  
--Declare                               
    --@v_EMAIL nvarchar
BEGIN                                   
SET NOCOUNT ON;                                     
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM LANDING_PAGE_PRUEBA WITH (NOLOCK) where idusuario = @IDUSUARIO)                             
Begin                               
    insert into LANDING_PAGE_PRUEBA                         
        (fechaCreacion,UsuarioCreacion,FechaModificacion,UsuarioModificacion,                       
        IdUsuario,Url_Img, Url_Href, Nombre_Image, Num_Id_Dashboard)                        
    Values                          
        (getdate(),@USUARIOCREACION,getdate(),@USUARIOMODIFICACION,
        (SELECT ISNULL((MAX(IdUsuario)+1),1) FROM LANDING_PAGE_PRUEBA),                     
        @URL_IMGN, @URL_HREF, @NOMBRE_IMG,
        (SELECT ISNULL((MAX(Num_Id_Dashboard)+1),1) FROM LANDING_PAGE_PRUEBA)
        );                      
end                             

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as afectadas                              
END
```

y este es mi método donde quiero insertar datos a partir de un formulario web

```
public Boolean AgregarRegistro_LandingPage(string UsuarioC, string UsuarioM, string nombreBanner, string Url_Image, string Url_Href)
    {
        //string msj = " ";
        bool correcto = false;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertaLandingPagePrueba", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USUARIOCREACION", UsuarioC);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USUARIOMODIFICACION", UsuarioM);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE_IMG", nombreBanner);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL_IMGN", Url_Image);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL_HREF", Url_Href);

            if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) != 0)
            {
                correcto = true;
                //msj = "Banner agregado correctamente";
            }

            con.Close();

            return (correcto);

    }
```

Si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería demasiado.

Comment: Si tu `@IDUSUARIO` ya lo generas adentro del procedimiento, no es necesario que se lo establezcas como parámetro para poder mandarlo llamar. Quítalo de tu listado de parámetros, decláralo como una variable como el correo electrónico y ya debe de jalar.

Comment: Me refiero al procedimiento almacenado, tu procedimiento ya genera `@IDUSUARIO`?

Comment: Lo que he asignado para @IdUsuario es con esto (SELECT ISNULL((MAX(IdUsuario)+1),1) FROM VIANNEY.LANDING_PAGE_PRUEBA). Antes de que me saliera este error insertaba datos sin problemas pero después de realizar algunos cambios me salia ya hora no almacena nada en la base de datos si lo intento desde localhost.

Comment: Y si quitas `@IDUSUARIO` de tu lista de parámetros del procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: No, me sale el mismo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es bastante claro, no estás mandando `@IDUSUARIO` a la hora de llamar al procedimiento desde el código.

Intenta lo siguiente: declara ese parámetro de manera que reciba un valor por default:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [VIANNEY].[sp_InsertaLandingPagePrueba]                                 
(
 @USUARIOCREACION       NVARCHAR(250),
 @USUARIOMODIFICACION   NVARCHAR(250),
 @IDUSUARIO             INTEGER = 0,    -- Valor por default
 @NOMBRE_IMG            NVARCHAR(250),
 @URL_IMGN              VARCHAR(200),
 @URL_HREF              VARCHAR(200)
)
```

y así no te marcará ese error. El cómo le hagas para darle el valor correcto en `where idusuario = @IDUSUARIO)` es otro tema.

Comment: muchas gracias, si me sirvió :D

Comment: ¡Me alegra mucho! Para eso estamos ;)